# SQL Server / Non-deterministic function impact?

Tags: sql-server

I read a lot about Deterministic vs Non-deterministic functions. Can someone explain this benefit of deterministic or impact of non-deterministic? I understand the difference between Deterministic vs Non-deterministic. But what I am looking for is a list of actions that are affected by it, by a function being non-deterministic. I understand now that computed columns is one such action. But are there more? Is there a list of everything impacted by a function being non-deterministic?

Comment: Please add some more information to your question to give it a context.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/140381/is-there-any-benefit-to-schemabinding-a-function-beyond-halloween-protection

Answer (score 0):

A deterministic function is one where, if you provide the same inputs, you always get the same output. A function that adds two integers (2 + 3) is always going to give the same answer (5).

There are places in SQL Server where you must use deterministic functions. For example, if you used a function in defining a computed column in a table, you can't have a situation where if it was recalculated, it'd come up with a different value for the same column and same row.

Where this causes a problem for many people is with functions like GETDATE(). It always returns a different value, so there are many places in functions where you can't use it.